# How to set templatefield cell position in row in dynamic gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm a newbie to asp.net. I created one dynamic gridview. In that I created two templatefields. I want to add two link buttons in the last two cells of each row. Here is my code:

```
 void grdv_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {                
            LinkButton lnkupdate= new LinkButton();
            lnkupdate.ID = "Update";
            lnkupdate.Text = "Update";
            LinkButton lnkdelete = new LinkButton();
            lnkdelete.ID = "delete";
            lnkdelete.Text = "delete";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Controls.Add(lnkupdate);
            e.Row.Cells[3].Controls.Add(lnkdelete);
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what is not working?

Comment: @Andi i want to set my link buttons in last two cells of the row.now i'm fixing in 2,3 cells.my datatable will change when user select one drpdown.so i want these two buttons at last of the row.

Comment: So the question is "how to use last two cells instead of cells 2 and 3"?

Comment: @ andrei yes. you are right.i want these two button in last two cells instead of 2,3.

Comment: Have you tried obvious `e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 2]` and `e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1]`?

Comment: @andi Thanks .my mistake .save the day.

Answer (score 0):

Andrei provided the answer in the comments, I'm just moving it out into a proper answer.

It was determined that nixen09 needs to access the last 2 cells in the row, this is one way to do that.

`e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 2]` and `e.Row.Cells[e.Row.Cells.Count - 1]`